# how to set Text on Image when i click JButton i set text but it occur in backside of Icon

Tags: java

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class TriImage implements ActionListener {
JFrame win = new JFrame();
ImageIcon icon1 = new ImageIcon("b1.jpg");
JButton b1 = new JButton(icon1);
JButton b2 = new JButton("help");
JButton b3 = new JButton("Continue");

TriImage() {
    win.setLayout(null);
    win.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 400);
    win.setBackground(Color.green);
    b1.setBounds(103, 0, 200, 200);
    b2.setBounds(200, 200, 100, 200);
    b3.setBounds(103, 200, 100, 200);
    win.add(b1);
    win.add(b2);
    win.add(b3);
    b1.addActionListener(this);
    b2.addActionListener(this);
    b3.addActionListener(this);
    win.show();
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if (b2 == e.getSource()) {
        b1.setIcon(null);
        b1.setText("Image 1");
    }

    if (b3 == e.getSource()) {
        b1.setIcon(icon1);
    }
}

public static void main (String arg[]){ 
   TriImage ob=new TriImage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the problem. it runs properly for me.

If you see the image without text, it's because the image is too big and has pushed the text outside where you can't see.